# Showing progress of Downloads inside Tkinter Tree View

Tags: python, tkinter, design-patterns

I have created a UI which have a tree view and the neccesary components for a downloader.
The UI related code for tree view is shown below.

```
from tkinter import ttk


def create_tree_view(self):
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height=10, columns=("link", "status"), style='Custom.Treeview')
    self.tree.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3, ipadx=15, ipady=25, sticky='e')
    self.tree.heading('#0', text='Count', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading("link", text='Download Link', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading("status", text='Download status', anchor='center')
    self.tree.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.tree.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    style = ttk.Style()
```

I have a downloader which follows strategy design pattern for downloading from various media. The code corresponding to the entry point of application is shown below.

```
# Necessary imports 

class Downloader:

    # Class Initialization happens here
        
    # UI Creation happens here 

    def on_add_links_button_clicked(self):
        stream_type = self.download_type_field.get().lower()
        stream_limit = int(self.limit_field.get())
        shut = self.shutdown_field.get()
        if stream_type in ['youtube', 'utube']:
            self.download_strategy(stream_limit, shut, youtube_regex, download_youtube_videos)
        elif stream_type == 'torrent':
            self.download_strategy(stream_limit, shut, torrent_regex, download_torrents)
        elif stream_type in ['fb', 'facebook']:
            self.download_strategy(stream_limit, shut, fb_regex, download_fb_videos)
        elif stream_type in ['insta', 'instagram']:
            self.download_strategy(stream_limit, shut, instagram_regex, download_insta_images)
    
    # Clear Input Logic

    # Showing Links in tree view

    def download_strategy(self, stream_limit, shut, regex_type, download_fn):
        _links = links_copied_to_clipboard(stream_limit, regex_type)
        self.show_links(_links, 'Started')
        self.tree.update_idletasks()
        download_fn(_links, shut)
        self.show_links(_links, 'Finished')
        self.tree.update_idletasks()

    # Main loop goes here
```

**PROBLEM**

I have defined a progress function for each strategies and the progress I was able to display in the terminal. But the Approach corresponding to updating the progress in the tree view currently was to show the download status after the process finished only. The dynamic update of tree view for the download progress is seemingly impossible.

**QUESTION**

Is this implementation of strategy design pattern able to support displaying download progress inside Tree View for a tkinter based application?

Comment: A lot of code to handle, you probably could get some answers, if it were simplified / you would hide unnecessary parts. Ideally, it should be really simple if you're talking / asking about design patterns

Comment: Create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without any dependencies on other libraries.

Comment: I have eliminated most  of the code and have provided the necessary information which needed for strategy design pattern.